# How to access UART registers which is a memory mapped IO at address 0x2530c00 in Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, uart

My board has a 8250 UART which can be configured in internal loopback mode. I want to test this UART and want to configure it for internal loopback. This UART is MMIOed at 0x2530c00 address. Can I do it through linux user level code? Or Do i need to write a kernel module? What are the functions I need to use to access the UART registers. My goal is  to set LOOP bit in MCTRL register and set the internal loopback mode and test the UART by sending data.

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have root access you can access the raw physical memory by opening the device `/dev/map` and then `mmap()`-ing the addresses you want to get.

Do not forget to use `volatile` pointers to read-write from that memory.

Also, if you need access to the I/O ports, read `man 2 ioperm` and `man 2 outb`.